# regex to detect id parts of a rails url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

Let's say I have a rails url printed out like this.

```
"/admin/corporate_pages/:corporate_page_id/carousel_items/:id/move_down"
```

How, using regex, would one substitute the parts of the url where an id is required, with say a 1. The desired output is something like this,

```
"/admin/corporate_pages/1/carousel_items/1/move_down"
```

The Id could appear at any point, so it musn't count the forward slashes for example to know when to substitute. It must detect when a colon is followed by a string.

I am playing around in http://rubular.com/ to do this. But as a newbie to Regex, and having just read

```
The road to hell is paved with regular expressions
- Ilian Iliev
```

I am beginning to feel nauseous.

Thanks

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Does the url contains only 2 ids??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex to match two `:{id_name}` using `/(:.+?)\//`

```
url = "/admin/corporate_pages/:corporate_page_id/carousel_items/:id/move_down"
url.scan(/(:.+?)\//).flatten
=>[":corporate_page_id", ":id"]
```

Explain:

```
(     -- Group start
 :    -- Start from : (:)
 .+?  -- Any char(.) repeat at least 1 time(+) ungreedy match(?)
)     -- Group end
\/    -- Stop with / (\/)
```

To replace two `:{id_name}` all to '1', need to change the regexp to `/:[^\/]+/`

```
url.gsub(/:[^\/]+/, '1')
=>"/admin/corporate_pages/1/carousel_items/1/move_down"
```

<kbd>[Regular Expression Test](http://regex101.com/r/cD4uZ9/2)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Try the regex

```
([^:]*):[^\/]*(\/[^:]*):[^\/]*(\/[^\/]*)
```

The match groups are

```
1.  /admin/corporate_pages/
2.  /carousel_items/
3.  /move_down
```

See the link for example http://regex101.com/r/cD4uZ9/2

Example:

```
"/admin/corporate_pages/:corporate_page_id/carousel_items/:id/move_down".gsub(/([^:]*):[^\/]*(\/[^:]*):[^\/]*(\/[^\/]*)/, '\11\21\3'
```

will produce output as

```
"/admin/corporate_pages/1/carousel_items/1/move_down"
```

**Explantion**

`([^:]*):` matches any thing upto first `:` ie  `/admin/corporate_pages/`

`[^\/]*` matches anything till next `/` ie `corporate_page_id`

`(\/[^:]*):` matches till next `:` ie `/carousel_items/`

`[^\/]*` matches till the next `/` ie `/id`

`(\/[^\/]*)` matches the rest ie `/move_down`

**EDIT**

If you want to replace every `:something` with `id`, a simpler regex would do the work

`:[^\/]*`

```
"/admin/corporate_pages/:corporate_page_id/carousel_items/:id/move_down".gsub(/:[^\/]*/, '1'
```

will produce output as

```
"/admin/corporate_pages/1/carousel_items/1/move_down"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but what if I add a string like this? "/admin/testimonials/:id/move_up"